# What are LPF and Socket/fallback in the output of dhclient -v?

Tags: output, dhcp, dhclient

Below is some sample output of that command:

```
$ sudo dhclient -v
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/eth0/00:15:5d:5a:e4:c5
Sending on   LPF/eth0/00:15:5d:5a:e4:c5
Listening on LPF/dummy0/6e:0b:72:f9:83:f0
Sending on   LPF/dummy0/6e:0b:72:f9:83:f0
Listening on LPF/bond0/82:a2:7e:03:69:19
Sending on   LPF/bond0/82:a2:7e:03:69:19
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x3115634c)
DHCPDISCOVER on dummy0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x1ab3dc37)
DHCPDISCOVER on bond0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xcea7a32d)
```

I couldn't find any documentation about what "LPF" or "Socket/fallback" are.
Could you please give some explanation and where to find out more about it?

The link https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/ didn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently LPF refers to Linux Packet Filter: https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp/-/blob/master/common/lpf.c

In other contexts, it's also known as [Linux Socket Filtering or Berkeley Packet Filter.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/filter.html)

A DHCP client needs to be able to send and receive broadcast UDP packets, while the network interface does not necessarily yet have a configured IP address. It also needs to care about which interface the packets will be passing through, in order to assign the network configuration to the specific network interface it was received on, and not to just any interface on a system that has more than one.

A packet-filter API, like LPF on Linux, is the most flexible and efficient way for the DHCP software to tell the OS's network stack: "I'm going to use a raw packet socket because my network traffic needs are a bit unusual, but I still don't want to receive a copy of *every single packet* that arrives through the network interface - just UDP packets on these particular port numbers."

If LPF or a similar packet-filter API is not available, the DHCP software would have to rely on the standard network sockets API and its various extensions - particularly socket options. But those are not uniformly supported on all the operating systems supported by the ISC DHCP suite, and so [the sockets code of ISC DHCP is rather complex](https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp/-/blob/master/common/socket.c) and full of `#ifdef`s.

If there is neither packet-filter API nor particular socket options available, the DHCP suite might work correctly only if the host has exactly one network interface:

```
#if !defined(SO_BINDTODEVICE) && !defined(USE_FALLBACK)
    /* Make sure only one interface is registered. */
    if (once) {
        log_fatal ("The standard socket API can only support %s",
               "hosts with a single network interface.");
    }
    once = 1;
#endif
```

When a packet-filter API is being used, the ISC DHCP suite also sets up a *fallback socket* using the standard network sockets API. On the receive side, a fallback socket just discards any arriving traffic: perhaps some packet-filter API will produce a *copy* of the incoming traffic, and the regular socket needs to be present to ensure the OS will not think the UDP port used for DHCP is closed, and cause ICMP error messages to be sent for any received unicast DHCP packets (i.e. refreshes of an existing active lease).

On the sending side, the use of a fallback socket is less obvious. If someone else knows more, feel free to edit this answer or add your own.